# Двоичное число в массиве и прибавление к нему

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, могу ли я, имея в массиве двоичное число, прибавить к нему единицу? К примеру, есть число 1011, соответственно оно у меня массив записано. Я прохожу массив циклом for и когда встречаю 0 увеличиваю его, но это неправильно, еще необходимо изменить все 1 до нуля на 0, а еще, если необходимо прибавить 1 к 1111, тут вообще непонятно.

Comment: Сконвертируйте оба числа в десятичные, проведите сложение, а потом сконвертите результат в новое двоичное число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно я не понял правильно, но int можно интерпретировать как массив из 32 двоичных разрядов.

А насчет алгоритма:

1. Ищете первый 0 с конца.
2. Если нулей не обнаружено, то увеличить размер массива на 1; сделать первым элементом единицу; остальные - нули. Иначе заменить все элементы массива, начиная с этого нуля, до конца массива на противоположные.

Comment: Спасибо, алгоритм помог.

Comment: Я бы упростил алгоритм до следующего:

    ищем первый 0 с конца, меняя единицу на ноль. Если не нашли, то добавим 1 к началу.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае нужно поразрядно пройти число, начиная с младшего, и использовать правила сложения двоичных чисел:

1. 0 + 0 = 0,
2. 1 + 0 = 1,
3. 1 + 1 = 0 и единица переносится в старший разряд.

Если при обработке самого старшего разряда числа возник перенос, необходимо просто добавить еще один элемент в массив. Для простоты можно использовать не массивы, а std::vector<int>, добавлять в него элементы гораздо проще.